# Is the following formula legal?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For all sets $M_i$ with $i \in I$ is the following term legal:

$\overline{ \bigcup \limits_{i \in I} M_i} ~ = ~ \bigcap\limits_{i\in I}^{} \overline{M_i}$

I don't know how the negation works on the left side..
I hope somebody can help.

Comment: It's legal. Don't shoot it.

Comment: What do you mean by $\overline M$?

Comment: The script says it's the complement of the set.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, those two expressions describe the same thing.  Think about it this way:  Take a bunch of sets $M_i$.  Put them all together in one big set.  Now look at everything that's *not* in that big set.  That's what's on the left side.

The right side says:  For each $i$, look at everything that's outside the set $M_i$.  The intersection then restricts you down to  only the things that are outside *all* of the sets $M_i$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the bar above means "complement" (a rather unusual notation) then yes, the equality holds.

An element is in the complement of the union precisely when if fails to be in all of the sets of the union.

Answer (score 0):

This formula is one of the so-called De Morgan's laws.

To prove that 
\begin{equation}
\overline{ \bigcup_{i \in I} M_i } = \bigcap_{i \in I} \overline{M_i}
\end{equation} 
let us choose $x \in \overline{ \bigcup_{i \in I} M_i }$. Then 
\begin{equation}
x \notin M_i \quad  \textrm{ for all } i \in I, \textrm{ i.e., } \qquad  x \in \overline{M_i}  \quad \textrm{ for all } i \in I.
\end{equation}
Consequently, we find that $x \in \bigcap_{i \in I} \overline{M_i}$, and hence
\begin{equation}
\overline{\bigcup_{i \in I} M_i} \subset \bigcap_{i \in I} \overline{M_i}.
\end{equation}
The converse inclusion follows similarly.